# Reusing function parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This will take a bit to explain.

I have a class called `Dependency`, which holds a value of generic type `T` and provides some helper methods (not really relevant here):

```js
class Dependency<T> {
    value: T
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to write another class, `Derivative`, that takes a list of dependencies and a `derive` function to generate some other value:

```
type DependencyArray = Array<Dependency<any>>
type DeriveFunc<T, D extends DependencyArray = DependencyArray> = (...deps: D) => Promise<T>

class Derivative<T, D extends DependencyArray = DependencyArray> {
    value: T
    constructor(
        dependencies: D,
        derive: DeriveFunc<T, D>,
    ) { ... }
}
```

Here's the catch – I want to restrict `derive` to only accept dependencies provided by first argument to `Derivative` constructor.
For example:

```
const depA = new Dependency<string>()
const depB = new Dependency<boolean>()

// Good: this one compiles
const new Derivative<string>([depA, depB], async ([a, b]) => `${a}-${b}`)

// Good: these two fail to compile, since arrays aren't the same length
// TS2345: Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 1.
const new Derivative<string>([depA, depB], async ([a]) => `${a}`)
const new Derivative<string>([depA], async ([a, b]) => `${a}`)

// Bad: in this one, `derive` function doesn't understand which types are in dependency array, so it merges it to Dependency<string | boolean>[]
// TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'boolean | string'.
//     Property 'length' does not exist on type 'false'.
const new Derivative<string>([depA, depB], async ([a, b]) => `${a.length}-${b}`)
```

Is there a way to reference **exactly the dependencies that were passed** to `Derivative` constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, TypeScript doesn't support what you're trying to do, since the types of array literals (`[1, 5, true, null]`) aren't imlied to tuples (`[ number, number, boolean, null]`), but instead to an array type (`(number | boolean | null)[]`). Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do about it. There's an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44309) you can take a look at, it describes exactly what you're trying to do.

Regardless, you can use the spread syntax instead:

```
class Derivative<T, D extends DependencyArray = DependencyArray> {
    value: T
    constructor(
        derive: DeriveFunc<T, D>,
        ...dependencies: D
    ) { ... }
}
```

In this way, argument types will get implied correctly. Unfortunately, there are no other workarounds, and if you want to use an array, you don't have a particular choice.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out using objects instead of arrays works just fine.
I had to switch to something like that:

```js
type DependencyMap = { [key: string]: Dependency<any> }
type DeriveFunc<T, D> = (deps: D) => Promise<T>

const new Derivative<string>({ depA, depB }, async ({ depA, depB }) => `${depA.length}-${depB}`)
```